# Nested records insert with knex.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, database, bluebird, knex.js

We have a database schema as below:

`students` table

| id | name | address |

A student has multiple education histories.

`education_histories` table

| id | degree | university | student_id |   #`student_id` is foreign key pointing student table

We get JSON structure from client side as like below:

```
{
    "name" :"Ram Neupane",
    "address": "Kathmandu, Bagmati",
    "education_histories": [
        {   
            "degree": "I.Sc.",
            "university": "Tribhuvan University"
        }, {
            "degree": "BE",
            "university": "Tribhuvan University"
        }
    ]
}
```

I am new to [Node.js](https://nodejs.org/) and [Knex.js](http://knexjs.org/). I want to insert `student` and nested `education history` on database using [bluebird](http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/getting-started.html) promise with Knex. How can I solve this problem.

I have tried with following promise:

```
function create (jsonParam) {
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
      knex('students')
      .insert({name: jsonParam.name, address: jsonParam.address})
      .returning('id')
      .then(function (response) {
        # Here, I want to insert record to education_histories table
      })
      .catch(function (err) {
        reject(err);
      });
    })
  }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Sorry to answer my own question But I want to explain only that how do i solve.

We can do the action by multiple ways

1. With reference to [Knex insert docs](http://knexjs.org/#Builder-insert), we can directly inset multiple records to table by just placing the json object in array. So, we have `jsonParam['education_histories']` which is an array, that containing `education_history` json object.

   ```
       var student_id = response[0];
       var educationHistoryParams = jsonParam['education_histories'];

       educationHistoryParams.forEach(function(educationHistory){
          educationHistory.student_id = student_id;
       });

       knex('education_histories').insert(educationHistoryParams)
       .then(resolve());
   ```
2. Another way is by using [Bluebird Promise.join API](http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api/promise.join.html) or [Bluebird Promise.map API](http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api/promise.map.html).

   ```
       var student_id = response[0];
       var educationHistoryParams = jsonParam['education_histories'];

       return Promise.join(
         educationHistoryParams.forEach(function (educationHistory) {
           educationHistory.student_id = student_id;

           new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
             knex('education_histories').insert(educationHistory)
             .then(resolve())
             .catch(function (err) {
               reject(err);
             })
           });
         });
       );
   ```